Does Spanish have words used as "verbal pauses"?
English tends to use the words "like" and "well" as verbal pauses, as well as non-word sounds like "um" (I believe linguistics calls these "fillers").  Does Spanish have any words that are commonly used this way?

In Spain, young people use: se pone for like.

You can find several, with explanations and examples of how to use them on:
https://www.spanishdict.com/guide/filler-words-in-spanish
https://www.fluentu.com/blog/spanish/spanish-filler-words/
These "fillers" are called "muletillas" in Spanish
Common 'Muletillas'
a ver   let’s see   This pause filler is used to buy yourself a little time to think.
bueno   so, well    Use bueno to introduce a statement or question or when you are hesitant to respond to a question.
digo    I mean  You can use this filler word to correct yourself after you misspeak.
entonces    so  This discourse marker is used to introduce a new topic or to help you get your thoughts together before speaking.
es decir   that is to say   Use this filler word when you want to clarify or restate something.
es que  it’s just that  Use es que to give an explanation for something.
mira    look, look here Mira is used to set the record straight or before going into a lengthy explanation.
o sea   in other words, that is to say  This hesitation form is used in the same way as the English fillers like and you know.
pues    well    This informal version of bueno is used to show uncertainty or indecisiveness. It’s also commonly used to introduce the answer to a question you weren’t expecting.
¿Sabes? You know?   Ask ¿Sabes? when you want to check someone’s understanding or if they are in agreement with you. Just like the "you know" in English
Region-Specific 'Muletillas'
en plan like, I mean    This meaningless filler is mainly used by young people in Spain in the same way like is used by English speakers.
este    um  In Latin America, this filler word is used in the exact way English speakers use uh or um. Spanish speakers tend to really drag out the last e.
esto    um, well    Use esto instead of este in Spain.
vale    okay    Arguably the most common word in Spain, this filler is used to agree with or affirm someone.

This is a link-only answer, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Many of those are discourse markers. not like "like" in English at all.

@Lambie es 'like' siquiera usado en el inglés como filler????? Se me hace q el op no está preguntando solo por el equivalente a esta palabra

@tac Sí, es verdad, pero toda esta lista no tiene solo fillers. Algunas lo son, otras no lo son.

@Lambie si sabés la respuesta y entendiste específicamente qué es lo que se pregunta, por qué no la redactás de una buena vez?

No voy yo decidir lo que es (lo) mejor en español. Pero sé que algunas no son muletillas. Algunos son marcadores de discurso hablado.

@Lambie: "Lo sé" no es una respuesta a la pregunta.

@tac There is no need to make insulting personal comments. I don't know. Got it? but I do know some of those are not fillers. That is all I am saying, and I have the right to give my opinion. This is not the first time you make insulting comments to me. I wonder why?? I could have 100 hundred years of experience but I know enough to say what I don't know. Do you have a problem with that?

@user37164 No he dicho "Lo sé" como respuesta.

@Lambie: "No voy yo decidir lo que es (lo) mejor en español. Pero sé que algunas no son muletillas." no me parece una repuesta que ofrezca más claridad.

@user37164 No se trata de una respuesta. Es un comentário. Dejame en paz.

Yes, "muletillas", but depends on the Spanish-speaking geographic zone.
Argentina: "este", "o sea"
Spain: "O sea", "Eh"
I don't know about other Spanish-speaking countries.

o sea is not like "like" in English.

El OP no está preguntando traducciones directas, sino palabras que se usan como muletillas para hacer pausas en el relato. "O sea" es una de las más comunes en español.

No, está preguntando por like. No es para hacer pausas. Es otra función.

@tac No hablo de culpa.
